# Can `mklink /J` be used to create symbolic links to files on windows?

Tags: windows, symbolic-link, junction

All the docs I found online (eg: https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042542/what-is-the-difference-between-ntfs-junction-points-and-symbolic-links etc) mention that `mklink /J` cannot be used for files, and must use absolute paths; however this seems to work (I tried this via cmd.exe on windows 10 via parallels on osx):

```
cat z2.txt
abc
mklink /J z2c.txt z2.txt
Junction created for z2c.txt <<===>> z2.txt
dir
...
01/30/2021  12:59 PM    <JUNCTION>     z2c.txt [C:\Users\timothee\tmp\foo\z2.txt]
cat z2c.txt
abc
rm z2.txt
cat z2c.txt
cat: z2c.txt: No such file or directory
```

this seems to show that `z2c.txt` created via `mklink /J` acts more like a symbolic link rather than a directory junction (eg: https://cects.com/overview-to-understanding-hard-links-junction-points-and-symbolic-links-in-windows/ mentions `If the target is deleted, its content is still available through the hard link`).

Note that on explorer, z2c.txt shows as a directory link and opening it via explorer doesn't work (gives: `The directory name is invalid`), but it does seem to work on cmd.exe.

The docs seem to contradict what I'm observing, and it looks like `mklink /J` can be used to circumvent the restriction on creating symlinks (must be admin or developper mode plus set `SYMBOLIC_LINK_FLAG_ALLOW_UNPRIVILEGED_CREATE`). Or it could also mean that some programs (`cat`) treat such links differently from others, in which case I'd like to know which programs understand such links.

Comment: Note that the quote from cects.com is specifically about hard links and _not_ about junctions (which are a form of soft links), so it really doesn't fit alongside "...acts more like a symbolic link rather than a directory junction".

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/hard-links-and-junctions also mentions: `Otherwise, junctions operate identically to hard links`; other sources too, eg: https://cects.com/overview-to-understanding-hard-links-junction-points-and-symbolic-links-in-windows/ `Junction Point (or directory hard link) is a type of hard link that acts like a representation of a directory, a partition or another volume.`

Comment: That's odd to find on Microsoft's own docs. Perhaps they meant to say they behave more *like* hard links than Explorer shortcuts (i.e. transparent at filesystem level versus opaque)? Despite that, junctions are reparse points which point to the target by its textual path, in nearly the same way as symlinks do.